# How to espace when calling jquery append?

Tags: jquery

I append the following html:

```
<span sytle="color:#000000" />
```

The color value is stored in a variable:

var my_color = "#000000";

var a = $("#a");

Below is what I have tried:

```
a.append('<span style="color: ' + my_color + '"</span>');
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the closing bracket on the span element:

```
my_color + '"></span>
             ^
```

Because there's no content within the span, are you sure that it's failing? Appending a `span` to the `#a` element wont change the color of the text within `#a`. An alternative might be to use:

```
$('#a').css('color', my_color);
```

Also, <sub>just in case</sub>, make sure your script is executing *after* the `#a` element has been added to the DOM, otherwise your selection will not be selecting *any* elements, and appending will fail.

You can simply wrap your code in a `document.ready` callback with the following code:

```
jQuery(function($){
  ...code here...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the end angle bracket of the span tag. To avoid creating HTML code like that you can use jQuery to create the element:

```
a.append($('<span/>').css('color', my_color));
```

(With a call like `$('<span/>')` jQuery will recognise that it's a single empty element and use `document.CreateElement` instead of parsing it as HTML.)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery has a [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method.

```
a.css("color","#000000");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a.append('<span style="color: ' + my_color + '"/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

**sytle** misspelling

**`$("#a");`** possibly you mean  **`$("a");`**

**`a.append('<span style="color: ' + my_color + '"</span>');`** is not correct - span not closed